# Render only one field of an entity

Tags: entities, 8

On my controller for a custom page I've loaded an entity and I want to render, on the template for this custom page, only a field of the loaded entity. I would like to get the render array for this field.

Is it possible?
I don't want to create a template for this content type only for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an example for D8:

```
$node = Node::load('1');
$display_settings = array(
  'label' => 'inline',
);
$build = $node->body->view($display_settings);
```

Comment: How would I render $build?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following code.

```
$field_to_render = field_view_field('model', $model, 'field_headerimage_image', 'full');
$field_to_render[$active_image]['#image_style'] = 'header_style';
$output = render($field_to_render[$active_image]);
```

Comment: Ehm, on Drupal8?

Comment: [field_view_field() and field_view_value() moved to view() methods on FieldItemListInterface and FieldItemInterface](https://www.drupal.org/node/2208327) would be the Drupal 8 equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet, otherwise I'd add this to the answer (https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/206821/71534) but it's also helpful to know how to get the `$display_settings` for your field.

1. Setup the field with Manage Display the way you want
2. Then you can check the config (e.g. `core.entity_view_display.node.page.teaser.yml`
3. Find the field you want under the `content` key in the root of the yml file,  which may look like this:

   ```
   content:
     body:
       label: hidden
       type: text_default
       weight: 22
       settings: {  }
       third_party_settings: {  }
       region: content
   ```
4. So in PHP you could set `$display_settings` to:

   ```
   $display_settings = array(
     'label' => 'hidden',
     'type' => 'text_default',
     'weight' => 22,
     'settings' => array(),
     'third_party_settings' => array(),
     'region' => 'content'
   );
   ```