# Get Field Manage Display configuration in node preprocess

Tags: 8

I am preprocessing the data and I have overridden the node template, during the preprocessing I am not able to figure out how can I respect "Manage Display" configs. As an example if date field is configured to have a specific format, or image field is configured to have specific Image Style.

So my question is how can I call the Manage Display configurations during node preprocessing.

Comment: Sounds like you are taking the wrong approach. If you render a field normally the config will be respected. What are you trying to do that doesn't allow you to do this.

Comment: I have a content type which has reference to paragraph(by paragrapgh module) A and paragraph A has further reference to paragraph B which has date field, now in node preprocess I am loading the referenced paragraph entity and and the date field does not take the Manage display configuration.

Comment: and since I am not letting the field rendered by field templates its not picking up the display formatters, so I was wondering if I can get the display config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @googletorp commented, the field should be rendered automatically considering the Manage Display configuration.

In my case [I was a node which has reference to paragraph A and A has reference to paragrapgh B which has a date field. The twig template markup needs heavy customisation so I was preprocessing the data to make it consumable by custom twig templates, now in order to get the date field show on node I have to load referenced paragraph entites and map the fields, because of which the fields was not rendering through the '#theme' => 'field' and Manage Display configs were not working.

But in order to make it working while mapping the field values we can can actually call for rederable field definition, something like

```
$date = $entity->field_date->view('full');
```

Comment: This is the answer for how to render a field by specifying a view mode. If you want to connect this to this question about the display configuration, you can use display options as parameter instead, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206813/render-only-one-field-of-an-entity/206821

Answer (score 0):

You can get the view mode

```
$viewmode = \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewMode::load('node.teaser')
```

or the display options

```
$displayoptions = \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityViewDisplay::load('node.article.teaser');
```

If you want to debug the configuration use `$viewmode->toArray()` or `$displayoptions->toArray()`.

In most cases you don't need this information in preprocess, because you have the result from the field formatter in the variable `content` and you would not want to build this from scratch again. If you want to change how a field is built use a custom field formatter.